# Why does this custom type definition not properly export a function?

Tags: typescript, definitelytyped

I have an npm dependency (`electron-is-accelerator`) in my Typescript project that comes with no types, neither as part of the package, nor as part of DefinitelyTyped. The dependency consists of a module with just one function accepting a string and returning a boolean. I wrote a type definition in `src/@types/electron-is-accelerator` as described in [this article](https://medium.com/@chris_72272/migrating-to-typescript-write-a-declaration-file-for-a-third-party-npm-module-b1f75808ed2):

```
declare module 'electron-is-accelerator' {
    export function isAccelerator(s: string): boolean;
}
```

I tried to execute this function like this:

```
import { isAccelerator } from 'electron-is-accelerator';

console.log(isAccelerator("Alt+Space"));
```

But I get the following runtime error:

```
TypeError: electron_is_accelerator_1.isAccelerator is not a function
```

How can I get this to run?

My `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./built",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es6",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "sourceMap": false
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*"
    ]
}
```

I uploaded a minimal demonstration example [here](https://github.com/303-cmyk/custom-type-definition-error) for anyone who wants to play with the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That [package](https://github.com/brrd/electron-is-accelerator/blob/master/index.js) uses CommonJS `module.exports` syntax to export the function:

```
module.exports = function (str) { ... };
```

`module.exports` is different from ES modules `default export` syntax and your named export declaration in the example above, so TS has [`export =`, `import = require()`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export--and-import--require) to express these imports/exports. `electron-is-accelerator` can be typed with following declaration:

```
declare module "electron-is-accelerator" {
  function isAccelerator(s: string): boolean;

  export = isAccelerator;
}
```

The import looks like this:

```
import isAccelerator = require("electron-is-accelerator")

isAccelerator("whatever")
```

If [`esModuleInterop`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) is enabled, you can write it as ES default import:

```
import isAccelerator from "electron-is-accelerator"
```